# Material UI chip input working weired with Korean charactor

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTvOX.gif)

A single word is detected as being separated into two. How should I solve it?

```
<ChipInput
   style={{ margin: "10px 0" }}
   value={tags}
   onAdd={(chip) => handleAddChip(chip)}
   onDelete={(chip) => handleDeleteChip(chip)}
   label="Search Tags"
   variant="outlined"
   />
```

Comment: Does this happen if you paste in the word from an outside source?

Comment: No. It was input directly. I think Korean Hangul is a 2bytes charactor, Unlike the Latin charactor.

Comment: The input should accept UTF-8.  In my current job we support localization but I speak Japanese not Korean.  With Japanese and Windows IME you type the syllables and when hitting the space bar it either converts the symbol or presents you with a choice of Kanji.  Does your IME work this way or do you have to use another key to cycle through?